# PHP DOMDocument isolating data from HTML

Tags: php, html, parsing, domdocument

I have tried a couple of approaches but with not so much succsses so my html goes like this:

```
<td>
  <a href="..?ID=343">
    <img src=".." />
  </a>
</td>
<td>
 <a href="..?id-343">  < - diffirence between two links is that this one has id in lowercase
  Some text..
 </a>
<td>
```

Now i want to get this element and this content:
     
      Some text..

I managed to get both information but for some reason if i print links_array i get double links:

> Array ( [0] => http://www.....net/2004/dealer_oglas.asp?id=5895417
>   [1] => http://www.....net/2004/dealer_oglas.asp?ID=5895417 [2] =>
>   http://www.....net/2004/dealer_oglas.asp?id=5883006 [3] =>
>   http://www.....net/2004/dealer_oglas.asp?ID=5883006 [4]

```
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.....net/2004/dealer_Zaloga.asp?dealer=12321");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($output);




    // Get images
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $image_array = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $images->length; $i++) {
        if($images->item($i)->getAttribute('width') == "80") {
            array_push($image_array, $dom->saveHTML($images->item($i)));
        }
    }

    // Get links
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $links_array = array();
    $title_array = array();

   //Here i try to compare the two a that it finds i want to store only the one that does not have img element right after it but for some reason it stores both.

    // All arrays are the same size img, links title
    for($j = 0; $j < $links->length; $j++) {
        if(isset($image_array[$j]) && $dom->saveHTML($links->item($j+1)) != $image_array[$j]) {
            array_push($links_array, 'http://www.....net/2004/' . $links->item($j)->getAttribute('href'));
            array_push($title_array, $links->item($j)->nodeValue);
        }
    }
```

I tried comparing nodeValue if its " " or "" but no succsses. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the link is actually in there twice?

`$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')` is a *global* search.

Comment: $links is an array of DOMDocument nodes since it grabs all a-s in content but in for($j ) loop i add what i found into the array and for some reason it still adds it twice.

Comment: What is the value of `$links->length`? You seem to expect `2`, but maybe it's `4`?

Comment: Its returning 66 twice the amount. Meaning it stored both a that sorround <img > element and the second a. I expect 1 but gives 2.

Comment: The thing is $links grabs both <a> elements however in my $links_array i only want to store the 1 that does not sorround the <img>

Comment: Yes .. difficult. This is why scraping is so mind numbing. Isn't there a better way to get the data you want - like a proper webservice?

Comment: Since there are allways 2 of everything i think at lease i solved it by changing the for loop at the end to $j+=2